# Getting black of a cell in a table

Tags: longtable, arrays, colortbl, rowcolor

In the following code, I tried to create two rows for each cell in the first column. I want the rows be colored. However, the first rows of the colored cell get black. How can I solve this problem?

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\biboptions{sort&compress}

\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % better than mathptmx
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newproof{pf}{Proof}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}%
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.925}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[2]{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

 \begin{tabular}{
 c
 >{\bfseries}S[table-format=1.4,detect-all]
 >{\bfseries}S[table-format=3.4,detect-all]
 >{\bfseries}S[table-format=3.4,detect-all]
 >{\bfseries}S[table-format=2.4,detect-all]
 }
 \toprule
 \centering
 Initial gains & 
 {$\max(x_1)$} & 
 {$\max(F)$} & 
 {$\max(\lvert\tau_1\rvert)$} & 
 {$\max(\lvert\tau_2\rvert)$} \\
 \midrule

 \splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6221 & 121.2892 & 149.8136 & 
 27.9641 \\

 \rowcolor{mygray}%
 \splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6221 & 120.5161 & 149.4271 & 
 34.7235 \\

 \splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6213 & 112.7963 & 148.2077 & 
  28.1165 \\

 \rowcolor{mygray}%
 \splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6213 & 112.7133 & 148.0053 & 
 34.9203 \\ 

 \splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6207 & 107.3273 & 281.3320 & 
 56.0344 \\

 \rowcolor{mygray}%
 \splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6193 & 92.9236 & 145.1045 & 35.5135 
 \\

  \splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6192 & 91.6388 & 281.3320 & 
  56.3469 \\ 

  \rowcolor{mygray}%
  \splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6187 & 86.6108 & 418.2479 & 
  76.9534 \\

  \splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6180 & 80.0001 & 281.3320 & 
  56.6598 \\

  \rowcolor{mygray}%
  \splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6189 & 89.1374 & 142.7592 & 
  30.0929 \\

  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

  \caption{Numerical values}
  \label{t1}

  \end{table}

  \end{document}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one more answer ...

- used packages `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` as in [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) answer
- for row coloring used `\rowcolors{3}{mygray}{white}` similarly as in [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) answer
- for multi line cells is used `makecell` from the package `makecell`, but they are determined as option of the first column (for shorter code)

**edit:**

the package `arydshln` is not compatible with many packages ... so it is cause of your problem: it doesn't "like" multi line cells constructed with inserting `tabular` environments or use of the `makecell` macro (which is based `tabular`).

as work around can be:

- make necessary changes in your preamble which is needed for work of my solution (replace `ansmath` with `mathtools`, and `color` and `colortbl` with `[...,table]{xcolor}`, see comments in my mwe below) and will not influence on your real document
- not use `makcell` as i did in my first propose
- instead `makcell` use column type `m{...}`

corrected code is:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\biboptions{sort&compress}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % better than mathptmx
%\usepackage{amsmath}            % for my answer should be replaced by "mathtools"
\usepackage{mathtools}           % mathtools load "amsmath"
    \DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
    \DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newproof{pf}{Proof}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}% better merge with "colortbl" package into "[table]{xcolor}"
                                         % my solution doesn't wirk with this package
%\usepackage{colortbl}                   % better merge with "color" package into "[table]{xcolor}"
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.925}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{table}[htb]
    \sisetup{detect-all}
    \rowcolors{3}{mygray}{white}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{
                >{$L_1=100$\newline
                  $L_2=100$}  m{11 ex}@{}
            >{\bfseries}S[table-format=1.4]
       *{2}{>{\bfseries}S[table-format=3.4]}
            >{\bfseries}S[table-format=2.4]
                    }
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Initial gains}
    &{$x_1$}
                & {$\max(F)$}
                                & {$\max(\abs{\tau_1})$}
                                                & {$\max(\abs{\tau_2})$}
                                                            \\
    \midrule
    & 0.6221    & 121.2892      & 149.8136      & 27.9641   \\
    & 0.6221    & 120.5161      & 149.4271      & 34.7235   \\
    & 0.6213    & 112.7963      & 148.2077      & 28.1165   \\
    & 0.6213    & 112.7133      & 148.0053      & 34.9203   \\
    & 0.6207    & 107.3273      & 281.3320      & 56.0344   \\
    & 0.6193    &  92.9236      & 145.1045      & 35.5135   \\
    & 0.6192    &  91.6388      & 281.3320      & 56.3469   \\
    & 0.6187    &  86.6108      & 418.2479      & 76.9534   \\
    & 0.6180    &  80.0001      & 281.3320      & 56.6598   \\
    & 0.6189    &  89.1374      & 142.7592      & 30.0929   \\[-\aboverulesep]
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Numerical values}
\label{t1}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit (2):**
in case, that you not like boldface numbers in table, than you only need to remove `>{\bfseries}` in `S` column type definitions.

**edit (3):**
the final version of the answer. it consider all your additional requests from your comments below answer:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\biboptions{sort&compress}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} 
\usepackage{mathtools}           
    \DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
    \DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newproof{pf}{Proof}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}% better merge with "colortbl" package into "[table]{xcolor}"
                                         % my solution doesn't wirk with this package
%\usepackage{colortbl}                   % better merge with "color" package into "[table]{xcolor}"
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.925}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{table}[htb]
    \sisetup{detect-all}
    \rowcolors{3}{mygray}{white}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{
            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{11 ex}
            S[table-format=1.4]
       *{2}{S[table-format=3.4]}
            S[table-format=2.4]
                    }
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Initial gains}
    & {$x_1$}   & {$\max(F)$}   & {$\max(\abs{\tau_1})$}
                                                & {$\max(\abs{\tau_2})$}
                                                            \\
    \midrule
$L_1 = 100$  $L_2=111$
    & 0.6221    & 121.2892      & 149.8136      & 27.9641   \\
$L_1 = 101$  $L_2=112$
    & 0.6221    & 120.5161      & 149.4271      & 34.7235   \\
$L_1 = 102$  $L_2=113$
    & 0.6213    & 112.7963      & 148.2077      & 28.1165   \\
$L_1 = 103$  $L_2=114$
    & 0.6213    & 112.7133      & 148.0053      & 34.9203   \\
$L_1 = 104$  $L_2=115$
    & 0.6207    & 107.3273      & 281.3320      & 56.0344   \\
$L_1 = 105$  $L_2=116$
    & 0.6193    &  92.9236      & 145.1045      & 35.5135   \\
$L_1 = 106$  $L_2=117$
    & 0.6192    &  91.6388      & 281.3320      & 56.3469   \\
$L_1 = 107$  $L_2=118$
    & 0.6187    &  86.6108      & 418.2479      & 76.9534   \\
$L_1 = 108$  $L_2=119$
    & 0.6180    &  80.0001      & 281.3320      & 56.6598   \\
$L_1 = 109$  $L_2=120$
    & 0.6189    &  89.1374      & 142.7592      & 30.0929   \\[-\aboverulesep]
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Numerical values}
\label{t1}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As I commented on egreg's response, I have some other commands and packages in preamble. Your code works fine alone but when I put it into the main file, I encounter a problem in which the output differs from when I compile it alone. I edited the code in the question in which you can see all of my packages and commands in preamble.

Comment: problem is package `arydshln`. do you really need them?

Comment: I had two more tables and for having beautiful tables I wanted to add dash lines in them. If there is no solution, I can remove it.

Comment: @AbbasKaramali, i edit my answer and resolve problem with `arydshln`. see (test) if my solution works in your document. observe suggested changes in your preamble!

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. It works fine. My last question is that if I want to change the bold font to normal font in the numbers of the table, what changes I should do in your code?

Comment: @AbbasKaramali, a t all `>{\bfseries}S[table-format=...]` remove`>{\bfseries}`. in this case also `\si\sisetup{detect-all}` is not necessary, but it is not harmful, so it can sty where it is. i will edit answer asap.

Comment: If I want to use different "L_1" and " L_2" for each row, would you tell me how to change the code? I wrote the code simply by using equal "L_1" and "L_2" for all rows to solve the main problem. How shall I change the code I want to use different "L_1" and "L_2"?

Comment: this request was not present in your question :-(. in this case you need to write correct values in each table row an one of advantages of will be lost. however, answer which you accepted, have this solution.

Comment: Thank you for your patience in solving my problem. I updated the best answer as yours. Thank you again

Comment: @AbbasKaramali, you are welcome! i make final revision of answer (delete intermediate answer phase, slightly improve table code). happy tex-ing!

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the tabulars in the first column with the  `\Vectorstack` command from `stackengine`. I also simplified the way to colour every other row using the `\rowcolors` command defined by `xcolor` with option `[table]` (which loads `colortbl`). Last, note a long table is automatically centred by default, and the `caption` command   must be used from within the long table, preferably in the `firsthead` part.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}%
\newcommand{\myrowcolour}{\rowcolor[gray]{0.925}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array, siunitx, stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}
\begin{document}

\bfseries\boldmath
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center, detect-weight}
\rowcolors{3}{white}{Gainsboro}
 \begin{longtable}{%@{}
  >{$}l<{$}>{\bfseries\boldmath}S[table-format=1.4]*{2}{>{\bfseries\boldmath}S[table-format=3.4]>{\bfseries\boldmath}}S[table-format=2.4]}
 \caption{Numerical values}
 \label{t1}
\endfirsthead
\toprule
\textbf{Initial gains}
 &{\textbf{max ($ x_1 $)}}
 &{\textbf{max($F$)}}
 &{\textbf{max($\vert\tau_1\vert$)}}
 &{\textbf{max($\vert\tau_2\vert$)}}
 \\ \midrule
\Vectorstack[l]{L_1=100\\ L_2=100} & 0.6221
 & 121.2892 & 149.8136 & 27.9641 \\
 \Vectorstack{L_1=100\\ L_2=100} & 0.6221
 & 120.5161 & 149.4271 & 34.7235 \\
\addlinespace
 \Vectorstack{L_1=100 \\ L_2=100} & 0.6213
 & 112.7963 & 148.2077 & 28.1165 \\
 \Vectorstack{L_1=100\\L_2=100}
 & 0.6213 & 112.7133 & 148.0053 & 34.9203 \\
 \Vectorstack{L_1=100\\ L_2=100}
  & 0.6207 & 107.3273 & 281.3320 & 56.0344 \\
 \Vectorstack{L_1=100\\ L_2=100}
  & 0.6193 & 92.9236 & 145.1045 & 35.5135 \\
 \Vectorstack{L_1=100\\ L_2=100}
  & 0.6192 & 91.6388 & 281.3320 & 56.3469 \\
 \Vectorstack{L_1=100\\ L_2=100}
  & 0.6187 & 86.6108 & 418.2479 & 76.9534 \\
 \Vectorstack{L_1=100\\ L_2=100}
  & 0.6180 & 80.0001 & 281.3320 & 56.6598 \\
 \Vectorstack{L_1=100\\ L_2=100}
 & 0.6189 & 89.1374 & 142.7592 & 30.0929\\[-\aboverulesep]
 \bottomrule
%
% \caption{Numerical values}
% \label{t1}
 \end{longtable}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Similar to but better than my effort!

Comment: Great minds think together! Why did you remove your solution? I find it quite interesting.

Comment: Because I thought it was sufficiently close to yours to be merely confusing to the OP. And yours correctly uses siunitx, which I had abandoned because I forgot about `boldmath`! The main thing is to get rid of the nested tables and the awful repetition of `\textbf`!

Comment: @ Bernard: Thank you for your nice answer. However, when I run your code on my system, the output is a little different. Unfortunately, I don't know how to post its image to show you my output.

Comment: @AbbasKaramali: In the edit window, the sixth icon from the left (looking like a mountain) is for inserting an image.

Comment: @ Bernard: I added the image of my output to the question

Comment: @AbbasKaramali: Quite strange… Did you compile the very code in my post, and nothing else?

Comment: @Bernard: I just copied and pasted your code in a new file and compiled it. I only receive one warning, "There are no bold math fonts" and the result is as the image.

Comment: @AbbasKaramali: It looks like the two rows of the `Vectorstack` command are superimposed.  Would you mind posting the code you compiled? Maybe it's  an encoding problem (I'm in UTF8).

Comment: @Bernard: I edited the code. I posted the code I compile.

Comment: @AbbasKaramali: I've just compiled your code and have no problem. Is your system updated? I had a few problems a couple of days ago with a recent updated of MiKTeX, which was solved since then.

Comment: @Bernard: No,it is not updated. I will try with an updated system again.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use boldface at all, but here's how you can do it; I changed `longtable` into `tabular`, as the present table is short, but the code would work the same for `longtable`.

For the headers, it's a tough choice, but I'd remove boldface completely: “max” is a math operator and it being bold might confuse the reader.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % better than mathptmx

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.925}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[2]{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
 c
 >{\bfseries}S[table-format=1.4,detect-all]
 >{\bfseries}S[table-format=3.4,detect-all]
 >{\bfseries}S[table-format=3.4,detect-all]
 >{\bfseries}S[table-format=2.4,detect-all]
}
\toprule
\centering
Initial gains & 
 {$\max(x_1)$} & 
 {$\max(F)$} & 
 {$\max(\lvert\tau_1\rvert)$} & 
 {$\max(\lvert\tau_2\rvert)$} \\
\midrule

\splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6221 & 121.2892 & 149.8136 & 27.9641 \\

\rowcolor{mygray}%
\splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6221 & 120.5161 & 149.4271 & 34.7235 \\

\splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6213 & 112.7963 & 148.2077 & 28.1165 \\

\rowcolor{mygray}%
\splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6213 & 112.7133 & 148.0053 & 34.9203 \\ 

\splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6207 & 107.3273 & 281.3320 & 56.0344 \\

\rowcolor{mygray}%
\splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6193 & 92.9236 & 145.1045 & 35.5135 \\

\splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6192 & 91.6388 & 281.3320 & 56.3469 \\ 

\rowcolor{mygray}%
\splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6187 & 86.6108 & 418.2479 & 76.9534 \\

\splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6180 & 80.0001 & 281.3320 & 56.6598 \\

\rowcolor{mygray}%
\splitcell{l}{$L_1=100$\\$L_2=100$} & 0.6189 & 89.1374 & 142.7592 & 30.0929 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Numerical values}
\label{t1}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I compiled your code in a new file and received the same output as you, however, when I use this code in another file which its preamble includes some other packages and commands, the same problem appear again. I think your preamble commands is inconsistent with one or more commands in mine. I edited the code and attached its output image. Would you tell me which command or package is inconsistent with your code?

Comment: @AbbasKaramali It's `arydshln`.